# BackgroundWorker freezes my UI and BeginInvoke seems to go turtle speed

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, backgroundworker

I have to do a very seemingly easy task: 1) list all files in a directory (and its sub-directories), 2) show them all in a multiline textbox and then 3) do some stuff inside each file. I'm stuck at 2) due to 2 problems, here's what I have:

1. `Form1.cs` is where I manage the UI and start a `BackgroundWorker`
   that runs the `Logic.cs`'s main function
2. `DependencyMapper.cs` is... well, where I do the folders/files thing (in `Fetch()`) and call a `Form1` method that populates each line (the current file's name) into a `Form1's` textbox using `BeginInvoke`.

**Less talk and more code.** This is the skinny, awfully working version of my code:

`Form1.cs`

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public DependencyMapper dep;
    BackgroundWorker bwDep;

    public Form1()
    {
        // I read here in SO to try put the BW stuff here don't know why, but hasn't helped.
        InitializeComponent();

        bwDep = new BackgroundWorker();
        bwDep.DoWork += bwDep_DoWork;
        bwDep.RunWorkerCompleted += bwDep_RunWorkerCompleted;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            bwDep.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
    void bwDep_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        dep.Fetch(extensions);
    }
    public void SendBack(string msg) // To receive Fetch()s progress
    {
        textBox2.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            textBox2.Text += msg + "\r\n";
            textBox2.SelectionStart = textBox2.Text.Length;
            textBox2.ScrollToCaret();
        }));
    }
}
```

`DependencyMapper.cs`

```
public class DependencyMapper
{
    private Form1 form;
    public DependencyMapper(Form1 form1)
    {
        this.form = form1;
    }
    public void Fetch()
    {
        DirectoryInfo folder = new DirectoryInfo(form.Texto1);
        FileInfo[] files = folder.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
        {
            form.SendBack(files[i].FullName); // Kind of talking back to the UI through form's reference and SendBack method which uses BeginInvoke.
        }
    }
}
```

So, does my app work? Yes, but two huge problems I can't solve:

1. It freezes the UI (wtf lazy `BackgroundWorker`?). Not completely because the textbox is adding each file one by one but like it's supposed to but I can't move the window around or click any buttons.
2. It's veeery slow. Definitely I'm doing something wrong. My app currently fills the textbox at a rate of 10 files per second approx. And I'm coding it to find particular snippets of text in hundreds of files...omg

PS: Before using `BackgroundWorker` I was using `Thread`: the UI didn't freeze at all but the textbox populating ratio was as slow. That's why I decided to venture with `BackgroundWorker` which only brought problem #1.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to put a  thread (Background) to be ready with the list of folders and files, before Form initialization. Think of ways to pass the list on Form construction or available on a global level.

Comment: `dep.Fetch(extensions);` What is dep? What is extensions? Where is Fetch function with parameter? Please post exact code. Consider passing only final relult `string[]` to the form, if this is applicable.

Comment: Threads are handy when you need to do something in the background. You are actually not benefiting from it since you continuously talk to the UI. The real benefit comes when you do your heavy operation entirely in the background and pass the results to your UI when it is done.

Comment: @Silvermind There is nothing wrong with updating the UI thread with the current progress. this is what `BackgroudWorker::ReportProgress()` is meant for. He is not using it for some reason, but in his code (at least the posted code) there is no heavy work on the UI thread.

Comment: @AviTurner Seems to me that this is bound to go wrong: `GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);` If you input `C:\ ` than this could take a long time. Every filename is being `SendBack` to the UI.

Comment: @AlexFarber Right, I forgot that part, updated the code thanks.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thing is I wanted to show the files as they are found (and processed, when I can get to coding that part) to give a realistic feedback of what's going on and also have a progressBar. (I used this line before: `IEnumerable<FileInfo> files = folder.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);`). I didn't know beforehand that DirectoryInfo would instantly get the whole list. How should I go around that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are *fire-hosing* the UI thread, producing results far faster than the UI can display them.  It might start off reasonably well, but gets worse and worse over time.  You force the TextBox to reallocate memory to find room for the appended string, copy the original text and append the new text.  This will seriously start to drag once the textbox contains a megabyte of text, give or take.  The same kind of problem that the System.String class has.  Which has StringBuilder as the fix, TextBox doesn't have anything similar.

The usual symptoms are that the UI thread will start burning 100% core.  At some critical point it goes completely catatonic, not repainting the UI anymore and getting unresponsive to input.  Because every time it updated the Text property, it has yet another delegate to invoke.  There's no time left to do the lower priority jobs, like painting and emptying the message queue.  The invoke queue itself starts falling behind, gather more and more invoke requests that are waiting to be processed.  In extreme cases that will crash your program with OutOfMemoryException but that takes a very long time.  Even when the background worker finishes, the UI thread is busy for quite a bit longer after that, trying to work down the backlog.

The UI is in general non-functional, even before it hits the wall.  The user is just staring at a blindingly fast scrolling textbox that does not permit actually reading anything.  Using a textbox in itself is very counter-productive, it doesn't make any sense for the user to edit the list.

Clearly you need to do this differently.  At least gather a whole bunch of files in a StringBuilder before you invoke.  That will give the TextBox a break having to reallocate so often.  It never makes sense to invoke more often than once every 50 msec, that's about as fast as a human eye can see changes without them turning into a blur.  Most programs that do this just show a *sample* of the files getting iterated so that the user has some feedback on progress.  In which case it is entirely reasonable to gather *all* the data in a StringBuilder and not update the TextBox until the file iteration completes.

Comment: I gave up on updating the user on the progress (I'm still coding the actual logic I want to do), and instead sending back the results all packed. But that was an incredible response, gave me a wide perspective, thank you.